# Reading string as text in an equation

Tags: python, string, for-loop, text

I want to be able to execute the following code:

```
import numpy
z=numpy.zeros(4)
k="z[i-1]"
for i in range(len(b)):
    z[i]=k
```

Which should return the same output as:

```
z=numpy.zeros(4)
for i in range(6):
    z[i]=z[i-1]
```

If I execute the first code block, I get an expected error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-982-3ba4e617a74a>", line 1, in <module>
    z[i]=(k)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'z[i-1]'
```

How can I pass the text from the string into the loop so that it functions as an equation, as if the characters from the string were typed by hand?

Comment: In what context are you trying to do this? Is `k` always in that format? The general solution is to use `eval()`, but it's slow and is not safe for arbitrary input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other then `eval` which is highly discouraged in production code, You can just as easily define a function that returns a specific item based on the array and index:

```
def k(arr,idx):
    return arr[idx-1]
for i in range(len(b)):
    z[i]= k(z,i)
```

If this rule needs to be applied in various spots in your code then you can edit the one function to apply that logic in all the places it is needed.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the [builtin `eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

Consider:

```
>>> z = numpy.zeros(4)
>>> k = "10 + z[i-1]"
>>> for i in range(1, 4):
...     z[i] = eval(k)
...
>>> z
array([  0.,  10.,  20.,  30.])
```

I made the expression a little more complex so you could see interesting output.

Answer (score 1):

Do it as following:

```
import numpy
z=numpy.zeros(4)
k="z[i-1]"
for i in range(len(b)):
    z[i]=eval(k)
```

But note eval can be a security problem: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html